# Android: ListView with multiple ImageViews (clickable) inflated from File

Tags: android

I want to get a listview of ImageViews, inflated from Files, and displayed like this:

[image: img]

They must be clickable (when i click it, I want to get it's path). Thanks.

Comment: use a custom grid view with num columns:5. Check http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use a custom grid view with num columns:5. Check javatechig.com/android/… –  Karthika PB

Thanks!